How to read a file with json-like objects in C with multithreading
I am trying to read a file with for multithread reading a file in C, but as I divide in chunks based on file size some may start/end in the middle of lines. I was trying to adjust the chunk size in case that happened. The lines don't have the same size. I am trying to read a very large file of about 100 MB.
First of all, is this a good approach or should multithread only be used for other tasks as, for example, processing the line?
My approach was to shift the start and the end of a chunk until it finds the end of a line. This way, if a chunk happens to be inside a line (for when n. of threads > n. of lines) the start and end will match and I will not start that thread. Most of the time it reads just fine, but sometimes, one line is not read, or a line is read twice by the same thread or a small portion of a line is read by another thread.
Is there any issue when different threads read the same file simultaneously?
long chunk_size = file_size / num_threads;

pthread_t threads[num_threads];
ThreadData thread_data[num_threads];

long last_end = 0;

for (uint32_t i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i)
{
    thread_data[i].stats = stats;
    thread_data[i].thread_tweets = NULL;
    thread_data[i].failed = 0;

    thread_data[i].file = file;
    thread_data[i].start = i * chunk_size;
    thread_data[i].end = (i == num_threads - 1) ? file_size : (i + 1) * chunk_size;
    
    if (i > 0)
    {
        if (thread_data[i].end < thread_data[i - 1].start)
        {
            thread_data[i].failed = 1;
            continue;
        }
    }
    int ch;
    // Adjust start position to the beginning of the next line
    if (!is_start_at_line_boundary(file, thread_data[i].start))
    {
        fseek(file, thread_data[i].start, SEEK_SET);
        while ((ch = fgetc(file)) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
        thread_data[i].start = ftell(file);
    }

    // Adjust end position to the end of the line
    fseek(file, thread_data[i].end, SEEK_SET);
    while ((ch = fgetc(file)) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
    thread_data[i].end = ftell(file);
    if (ch != '\n' && ch != EOF)
    {
        thread_data[i].end++;
    }
    // If they coincide, the chunk was inside a line and the thread shoudnt run
    if (thread_data[i].end == thread_data[i].start)
    {
        thread_data[i].failed = 1;
        continue;
    }
    if (i > 0)
    { 
        thread_data[i].start = last_end;
    }
    if (pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, read_file_chunk, &thread_data[i]))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating thread\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    last_end = thread_data[i].end;
}

int is_start_at_line_boundary(FILE *file, long start)
{
    if (start == 0)
    {
        return 1; // Start of the file
    }
    fseek(file, start - 1, SEEK_SET);
    if (fgetc(file) == '\n')
    {
        return 1; // Start is at the beginning of a line
    }
    return 0;
}

The function read_file_chunk will use fseek() to go to the start of the chunk and read with fgets() the whole chunk where it calls a parsing function for each line, as each line contains an individual json like format, which instead of , has ;, e.g.:
{"created_at": "2020-01-14 12:00:00"; "hashtags": ["A", "B"]; "id": 546542; "uid": 1500}
Should I use a json library and not assume each line is a json object? Will this be more efficient and sensible?

There is no clear question in your post. The only sentence with a question mark is “Maybe should I only multithread the processing of each line and other tasks?” Edit the title and the body to contain a clear question. Generally, there is not much to gain by multithreading reading of a single file, as the multiple threads will compete for a single resource. Multithreading process of data can be beneficial. However, you do not describe what processing you will perform, particularly what the consequences of dealing with line fragments are.

Please post a complete example.  What does read_file_chunk() do, for example?  And reading a file byte-by-byte to find where lines start and end is likely going to be so slow as to make any possible gains from threading wasted.  You're reading each byte of the input file at least twice, and each time you call fseek() you flush the buffer and require the data to be read over and over - and most implementations read something like a full 8 kb buffer.  If the lines are short, you may be reading each byte from disk literally thousands of times for a large file.

And if you're sharing a single FILE * between threads, every time any thread does an fseek() the file position for all the other threads is also changed, and every time a thread reads from the FILE * stream, the data it reads won't be read by any other thread.

Unless every line in the file is the exact same length, you can't divide it up before you have actually read the file. So start with that, read into an array of lines. Once you have done that you know how many lines there are, and also have the data in memory, and so can split the lines evenly among the threads.

And if the lines of the file are all exactly the same size, then I recommend you memory map the file instead, and pass pointers to the threads.

@EricPostpischil I just assumed that each line had a json-like object and couldn't think of how I could process a line fragment

@AndrewHenle So, basically just can't be implement, as is more inefficient and if fseek changes the position for every thread than it doesn't really work

@Someprogrammerdude So, I would read the entire file into an array with a MAX_LINE_SIZE for example, and then I could split?

@thuruk9 It can be done, but you have to be really careful about how you do it, and if you're using only one FILE * stream you simply can't read from the same file from multiple threads at the same time.  And you have to also realize seeking and then reading is not a atomic operation, so you either have to provide a mutual exclusion lock of some kind on the file so each thread can lock it, use multiple FILE * streams, or use platform-specific functions that read from a specified offset atomically like POSIX pread() or Windows ReadFile() using OVERLAPPED.

(cont) And, since you're presumably using multithreaded reading for performance reasons, you have to be careful that partitioning the data doesn't make things slower than just using one thread and keeping things simple.


I am trying to read a very large file of about 100 MB. First of all, is this a good approach or should multithread only be used for other tasks as, for example, processing the line?

Very roughly, a typical hard drive read speed is 150 MB/s. For an SSD, it might be 400 MB/s.  Many factors affect actual throughput, but I think it's safe to assume that a single threaded sequential read of a 100 MB file shouldn't take more than 1 second.  It could be substantially faster if the file is "hot" (cached by the filesystem or OS).
Both HDDs and SSDs are sequential devices, so even if you have multiple threads trying to read different chunks of a file at the same time, each thread will likely have to wait for other threads' reads.
In my experimentation, if you need to read an entire file into memory, the simplest way is also the fastest:  Issue one read for the entire file.
(Mapping a file into memory can be a good idea if you expect that you might not need to bring the entire file into memory and/or you need read the file out of order.  Neither seems to apply to your case.)
Beware of premature optimization.  Start with a working single-threaded implementation.
If it's not fast enough, then you have to measure to figure out where the bottleneck is.  In your case, it might be the time it takes to read the file into memory or it might be the JSON parsing.
If reading the file is the bottleneck, I'd look for solutions other than multithreading.
If parsing the JSON is the bottleneck, multithreading might be one possible solution to explore.  In that case, I'd initially leave the single-threaded i/o as is and apply multithreading to the parsing of the data.
(I'm not denying that there are some circumstances where you might want to break the read up into portions, but I wouldn't start there.)

Thanks! But should I use fgets to read the file line by line and, then, parse it or is there a better option?

I believe you are overthinking this and making it harder than it is.
First of all, if possible, use standard json for your file and an existing json library for parsing it. 100MB is not really that big.
The time it takes to read the file from disk is going to dwarf the time it takes to parse it.
Now I am going to imagine that each object you have needs to be processed and might take 1 second to do so.
The first implementation you try should be to read in and parse the file in a single thread, then partition the work for your threads. If the objects are in an array, you could pass  a start pointer and a count to each thread.
If you really want to parse the file in different threads, I would still read the file into memory in a single thread. While reading, either count parenthesis or line endings to find where to break up the file. As each chunk completes,  hand that chunk off to a thread.

Thanks. So, the approach is to use fread the file in a go? How can I then break up the work for the other threads, save the chunk as an array which has all the lines of a chunk?

@thuruk9 In the main thread after reading, scan the input buffer for line endings if each object is on a line. That way you can figure out where to break up your file. Then pass a pointer to the start of each chunk, and a buffer size  to each worker.
